# Python SPARQLWrapper: specifying URIs doesn't work

Tags: sparql, sparqlwrapper, wikibase

I use the following Python code to retrieve all triples from my sparql endpoint:

```py
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON
import sys

def get_results(endpoint_url, query):
    user_agent = "WDQS-example Python/%s.%s" % (sys.version_info[0], sys.version_info[1])
    sparql = SPARQLWrapper(endpoint_url, agent=user_agent)
    sparql.setQuery(query)
    sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
    return sparql.query().convert()

endpoint='https://music.wikibase.cloud/query/sparql'
query="""construct where {?s ?p ?o.}"""
get_results(endpoint,query)
```

This works, it gives me all triples, and I see one of them has the predicate `https://music.wikibase.cloud/prop/direct/P2`. Now I want to list all triples with that predicate, so I execute:

```py
query="""construct where {?s <https://music.wikibase.cloud/prop/direct/P2> ?o.}"""
get_results(endpoint,query)
```

Yielding no results, but we have seen in the first query that there *are* triples with that predicate.

Using the sparql web interface at https://music.wikibase.cloud/query, the second query works as expected. What am I doing wrong in the Python code?

Comment: additionally, I tried the same with the more common `SELECT *` instead of `CONSTRUCT`. The same problem arises.

Comment: do `sparql.setMethod(POST)` and `sparql.setReturnFormat(RDFXML)`

Comment: it should be `sparql.setMethod("POST")` but that indeed works.

Comment: @UninformedUser @Marijn thanks, adding `sparql.setMethod('POST'); sparql.setReturnFormat('RDFXML')` to the function works.

Comment: both are aliases contained in the package, thats why I did not use strings here: `from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, RDFXML, POST` - I prefer the built-in variables to avoid typos etc. Indeed, in the end the methods take strings as argument